# How can I keep nuget from updating dependencies?

Tags: nuget, common.logging

I'm attempting to install a nuget package which has incorrectly specified one of it's dependencies.  Common.Logging.Log4Net requires log4net = 1.2.10 however the nuget package specifies log4net >= 1.2.10.  Even if I manually install the older version of log4net, nuget upgrades log4net to 1.2.11 when I install Common.Logging.Log4Net.  How can I get nuget to bypass dependency resolution or at least prefer installed packages of a sufficient version?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In order to bypass dependency resolution you can use the `-IgnoreDependencies` option:

```
Install-Package -IgnoreDependencies ThePackageName
```

---

You should be able to lock the package to a specific version by hand-editing the packages.config and setting the allowedVersions attribute to indicate the version span you want to allow.

```
<package id="Common.Logging.Log4Net" version="1.2.10" 
     allowedVersions="[1.2,1.2.10]" />
```

Note that his will however not upgrade the version of the package at all even when explicitly updating the package.

See the [nuget versioning documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/Versioning) for more info on versioning.